# Flutter : "Instance member 'playing' can't be accessed using static access."

Tags: android, flutter, text-to-speech

I try to create Text to speech for my Flutter Project ,  i cant call "playing" functions in view.

Here is my code :

```
void initSpeechRecognizer(){
    FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();

    Future _speak() async{

      var result = await flutterTts.speak("Hello World");

      if (result == 1) setState(() => flutterTts = _VoiceHomeState.playing);

      List<dynamic> languages = await flutterTts.getLanguages;

      await flutterTts.setLanguage("id-ID");

      await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(1.0);

      await flutterTts.setVolume(1.0);

      await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);

      await flutterTts.isLanguageAvailable("id-ID");

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this line cause error

```
 if (result == 1) setState(() => flutterTts = _VoiceHomeState.playing);
```

flutterTts is an instance you have init in initSpeechRecognizer

in example code of Fultter_TTS

```
TtsState ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
...
var result = await flutterTts.speak(_newVoiceText);
    if (result == 1) setState(() => ttsState = TtsState.playing);
  }
```

I think you are trying to set TtsState. but typo to flutterTts